# Android app dev, custom numberpicker for api level 8

Tags: java, android, numberpicker

I am trying to create a custom number picker for applications that require minimum of API level 8, so far I got this code, it is simple but I don't know how to fix this error I get.

The code so far is this:

package com.example.symbol_temp;

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Integer counter=0;
        Button add,sub;
        final TextView display;

        add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.plus);
        sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.minus);
        display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.showtemperature);

        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
            counter++;
            display.setText( "" + counter);
            }
        });

        sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
            counter--;
            display.setText( "" + counter);
            }
        });

        }

}
```

and the XML is this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.symbol_temp.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/showtemperature"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/minus"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/showtemperature"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="+" 
        android:onClick="add"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/plus"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/minus"
        android:layout_below="@+id/showtemperature"
        android:text="-" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Getting this in LogCat:

```
04-14 13:31:59.222: E/AndroidRuntime(359): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-14 13:31:59.222: E/AndroidRuntime(359): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.symbol_temp/com.example.symbol_temp.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-14 13:31:59.222: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
04-14 13:31:59.222: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
04-14 13:31:59.222: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
04-14 13:31:59.222: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
04-14 13:31:59.222: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-14 13:31:59.222: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-14 13:31:59.222: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-14 13:31:59.222: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-14 13:31:59.222: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-14 13:31:59.222: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-14 13:31:59.222: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-14 13:31:59.222: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-14 13:31:59.222: E/AndroidRuntime(359): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-14 13:31:59.222: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at com.example.symbol_temp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
04-14 13:31:59.222: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-14 13:31:59.222: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
04-14 13:31:59.222: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  ... 11 more
```

I think I have changed few things, line number 24 is this :

```
add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
```

Thank your for your help.

Comment: add is null is the posted xml `activity_main.xml`??

Comment: fragment_main.xml is it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment and

```
tools:context="com.example.symbol_temp.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment"
```

I assume that the views belong to `fragment_main.xml`.

You inflate the wrong layout. And you are looking for the view in the wrong layout.

Change this

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

to

```
setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
```

Also change this

```
Integer counter=0;
```

to

```
int counter; // primitive data type
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     counter =0;
```

Comment: I think it will work, I know how this newb compiler builded the APP because I get this errors:
Cannot refer to a non-final variable counter inside an inner class defined in a different method MainActivity.java /Symbol_TEMP/src/com/example/symbol_temp line 27

Comment: @MarianP check the edit. you need to make `Integer counter=0` to `final Integer counter=0` or do as suggested in my post because you are accessing the same in annonymous inner class

Answer (score 0):

Your counter variable is declared inside method thats why when you trying,  move your variables above onCreate method.

Comment: @MarianP just make it `final Integer counter=0;`. But use primitive data type int

Comment: And remember if you want to save state of your counter when you rotate device or minimize your app override activity methods on saveInstanceState() to save your counter status and in onCreate() retrive that value and assing to your counter

Comment: It would be amazing if I would know how to do this, yes I tryed now and when I rotate in emulator my counter reset.

Comment: Use this method

`protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstance) {
  super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstance);
  savedInstance.putInt("myCounter",counter);
}`
Then in `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
if(savedInstanceState != null){
counter = savedInstanceState.getInt("myCounter"
}
}`

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE:** 
 This answer is posted as answer for coment posted by person who asked this question. I've  posted this as answer for brevity


Use this method 
`protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstance) {
   super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstance); 
   savedInstance.putInt("myCounter",counter); }`

 Then in

```
  onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){ 
  if(savedInstanceState != null)
  counter = savedInstanceState.getInt("myCounter")}
```

From savedInstance that is object of Bundle class you can retrive your saved value and assign it on create. Remember to check if value is null, because if you run your app first time your counter may not be instantiated yet and it will throw exception. 
Also when you retriving savedValues make sure you don't overwrite them.

Comment: I have done how you sayd, I have 2 problems,I put in portrait view value 25, when I switch to landscape I get the default value, when I switch back, I still get default, put when I press button for + or - I get the value where I remained with an Incrementation or decrementation.

Comment: On create if savedInstance isn't null when you obtain your saved value you have to assign it to your textView to display it.